# Heroku not showing uploaded photos using Paperclip and AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm using paperclip to load photos to a heroku site. I don't get any errors and my object is created but I don't have the photo.
The gem versions I'm using are:

```
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.6'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
```

My config settings are all correct and I'm on Oregon region so I've set the AWS_REGION to 'us-west-2'.
I believe my production.rb is set up correctly,

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION'),
  }
}
```

And my company model that should have the photo is

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :logo_image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", 
                                           thumb: "100x100>" }, 
                    :default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("noimage1.jpg")
```

In my heroku logs:

```
[paperclip] saving /companies/logo_images/000/000/743/original/baking.jpg
[AWS S3 200 0.218362 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,
    :bucket_name=>"mybucketname", :content_length=>64071,
    :content_type=>"image/jpeg",
    :data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter: baking.jpg,
    :key=>"companies/logo_images/000/000/743/original/baking.jpg")
```

I'm rendering the image to my show page this way:

```
<%= image_tag(@company.logo_image.url(:medium)) %>
```

It looks to me my photo is saving to the bucket but for some reason it's no rendering to the page.

Comment: Can you upload the code you are using to display the image in your view?

Comment: I updated with the relevant code.

Comment: When I first set AWS up what really helped me was, if you go into the AWS console and view the image you can get the url for that image in ti's properties on the right.  If you have not yet, inspect the page and make sure it matches what is in the view first and start debugging from there.  Or have you already tried doing that?

Comment: I just figured out the problem but thanks for the tip. I'll use that going forward.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding url and path attributes to my config.paperclip_defaults in my production.rb

```
url: ":s3_domain_url",
path: ":class/:id.:style.:extension",
```